# Php file tries to download instead of execute code

Tags: php

I have the following in my .php file.  Just trying a simple search on Flickr.  When I visit this .php page in my browser a download dialog pop up.  I was expecting to see the json echoed out on the page. I am using WAMP and have url `fopen()` enabled.If I comment out this code and echo out "WORKING" it does work just fine.

```
$api_key = "MYKEYHERE";
$tag = 'flower';
$perPage = 25;
$url = 'http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search';
$url.= '&api_key='.$api_key;
$url.= '&tags='.$tag;
$url.= '&per_page='.$perPage;
$url.= '&format=json';
$url.= '&nojsoncallback=1';
header('Content-Type:text/json;');
echo file_get_contents($url);
```

Seems something is wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this previous question that I answered about the same issue:

[How can I prevent user-agents from presenting a download window for unrecognized mime types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653445/how-can-i-prevent-user-agents-from-presenting-a-download-window-for-unrecognized/1653467#1653467)

Comment: Great little plugin.Worked a treat.Thanks